# When using stored procedures to update/modify a given table, how can I detect if I am inserting numeric where characters are normal entry?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a error handler inside my stored procedure which will tell me if my IN parameters ('STATE' and 'ZIP') have numeric and character entries, respectively.

(NOTE: skip down two paragraphs if you understand what I am asking help with.)

I created a database(temp) and in that database I created a table, temp1.  And then I created a stored procedure to populate that table, this STORED PROCEDURE,proc_handler, has its IN parameters corresponding to the columns in the TABLE, temp1.  And it has one OUT parameter named out_status which is related to error handler.

I have a error handler for Duplicate primary key.  For example at the bottom of my code, CALL proc_handler(...), will store "Duplicate Entry" in the OUT parameter if MySQL gives the following response;( Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'xxx xxxxx' for key 'PRIMARY'); and "OK" otherwise.
This works fine.

Now Setting up a error handler seems simple enough(for some error code),but if I try to input '1CA' in the STATE column, how can I detect that there is a numeric entry and give a warning in the OUT parameter.  Or similarly if for ZIP entry the is input '95ABC' I want to give the warning that characters were inserted in the ZIP column.

Being new to programming I have come across one suggestion that mention using regex and IF THEN statement to perform this, is that the correct advice?  Is it possible to give commands within stored procedure to test is an IN_parameter contains unexpected numeric or character entry?

```
USE temp;
DROP TABLE temp1;

CREATE TABLE `temp1`(
`idAddress` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`Street1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`City` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`STATE` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`ZIP` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
`Country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`idAddress`));


#  Stored Procedure to populate temp1, the table created above:

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_handler$$

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_handler 
        (IN idAddress_in INT(11) ,
         IN Street1_in VARCHAR(45) ,
         IN City_in VARCHAR(45), 
         IN State_in VARCHAR(45), 
         IN ZIP_in VARCHAR(5), 
         IN Country_in VARCHAR(45),
         OUT out_status VARCHAR(30))

    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062
        SET out_status='Duplicate Entry';

    SET out_status='OK';

    INSERT INTO temp1 
        (idAddress, Street1, City, STATE, ZIP, Country) 
    VALUES 
        (idAddress_in, Street1_in, City_in, State_in, ZIP_in, Country_in);
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

####    Test for error handler   ###

CALL proc_handler(111, '5806 Ridgemore CT','Orangevale','CA','95675','USA',@status);
SELECT @status;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one:
Numeric:

```
set @sam ="4 sample";
select @sam REGEXP ('[0-9]');
```

It will return 1 if it has a numeric value otherwise return 0;

Alphabet:

```
select @sam REGEXP ('[A-Za-z]');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Always aware primary key constraints in your table, primary is a unique key and  it cant be repeated.

Comment: Thanks that worked to detect numeric, could you also tell me how to detect alphabets in a variable. BEST.

Comment: Both check wethier  Alphabet or Numeric.